# how does one integrate Mixpanel into flutter applications?

Tags: android, flutter, mixpanel

i followed the steps given here
and after adding this

```
  import 'package:mixpanel_flutter/mixpanel_flutter.dart';
  ...
  class _YourClassState extends State<YourClass> {
  Mixpanel mixpanel;

  @override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();
  initMixpanel();
   }

  Future<void> initMixpanel() async {
   mixpanel = await Mixpanel.init("Your Mixpanel Token", optOutTrackingDefault: false);
 }
...
```

the terminal is giving me an error saying

```
Field 'mixpanel' should be initialized because its type 'Mixpanel' doesn't allow null.
Mixpannel mixpannel;
failed to compile application
```

i have inserted the mixpannel token.
in Mixpannel, i started a test project added an event chart for all events.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the example which is given by [mixpanel-flutter](https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-flutter)

You can create the instance for it:

```
class MixpanelManager {
  static Mixpanel? _instance;

  static Future<Mixpanel> init() async {
    if (_instance == null) {
      _instance = await Mixpanel.init("YOUR_PROJECT_TOKEN",
          optOutTrackingDefault: false);
    }
    return _instance!;
  }
}
```

And you can use likewise (in other class):

```
  late final Mixpanel _mixpanel;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initMixpanel();
  }

  Future<void> _initMixpanel() async {
    _mixpanel = await MixpanelManager.init();
  }
```

Check out the [example](https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-flutter/blob/main/example/lib/event.dart) for more.

Comment: So it should be initialized in every stateful widget?

Answer (score 0):

As Pratik Butani said it, we can make a single instance of mix panel and then initialiaze it in your main.dart file and use it throughout the application.

```
class MixpanelManager {
static Mixpanel? _instance;
static String projectToken = "your_token";
static Future<Mixpanel> initMixpanel() async {
if (_instance == null) {
  _instance = await Mixpanel.init(projectToken, 
trackAutomaticEvents: true);
}
return _instance!;
}

static Mixpanel get instance {
assert(_instance != null, "Mixpanel must be 
initialized first");
return _instance!;
}
}
```

in the above code, you can see that I have made a get method for the instance.

and to initialize it in the main.dart file

```
      Future<void> main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await MixpanelManager.initMixpanel();
runApp(YourApp());
}
```

then you can use this single instance anywhere on a tap event like below .

```
MixpanelManager.instance.track('log in: 
${session.user.email}',
      properties: {"user": "${session.user.email}", 
  "login": "true"});
//or without properties
MixpanelManager.instance.track('going to Accounts 
Screen');
```